# OpenCV 3.1.0 in JAVA on Mac - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv, exception

I have been struggling for about a week now making OpenCV 3.1.0 work on my macbook - still no success..

I have been using this guide:
http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-0-under-linux-or-mac which includes CMAKE to generate a opencv_java310.jar file and the libopencv_java310.so. I recently found out that .so files are for Linux OS, so to make it work on MAC OS all I have to do is re-naming the libopencv_java310.so to libopencv_java310.dylib.

The renaming of the library file (.so --> .dylib) seems to work for everyone but me. Eclipse throw me this Exception:
[my program for  testing if OpenCV works properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4cVV.png)
.
Do you guys have any idea of what this means and how to fix it?
Any help is VERY appreciated :)

Comment: For future reference, please copy/paste the exception stacktrace directly in your question instead of linking to remote site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

If you are following this guide: http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-0-under-linux-or-mac

all you have to do, when finished, is to execute the following command ind the folder containing libopencv_java310.so

ln -s libopencv_java310.so libopencv_java310.dylib

You welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Could Solved the same problem as below.
step 1: rename -> libopencv_java310.so to libopencv_java310.dylib
step 2: keep opencv-310.jar and libopencv_java310.dylib in one folder
step 3: Add opencv-310.jar to eclipse preference in user Libraries. After adding expan jar and edit Native library location to the folder where libopencv_java310.dylib is kept.
step 4: Add opencv library in your project.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but it didn't work. But thanks for trying. I have been forced to install Windows in Bootcamp to be able to participate in my course.